# Retrieving codes within parenthesis in ColdFusion version 4.5

Tags: regex, coldfusion

I have a string retrieved from the database that can contain a series of codes in either {} or [] brackets as well as plain, user entered text. For example, each of the following would be possible values:

```
[code]

[code1][code2]

{code}

{code1}{code2}

{code1} Some user entered text. {code2}{code3} Some more user entered text.

Etc. etc.
```

What I need to do using ColdFusion is extract the codes within the {} and [] brackets so I can retrieve their descriptions from a database. For example:

```
{code1} Some user entered text. {code2}{code3} Some more user entered text.
```

Would become a list similar to:

```
{code1}|{code2}|{code3}
```

Normally I could just do something like REMatch but unfortunately I'm stuck doing this on a server running **ColdFusion version 4.5** (groan) so my options are limited.

I'm thinking maybe I could do some Replaces on the string to convert it into a pipe delimited list that I can then easily process but I'm not sure if there might be a more straight forward approach? I'm not even really sure what a sensible way to process this using a Replace would be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<cfset myString = "{code1} Some user entered text {code2}{code3} More user entered text" />
<cfset myArray = listToArray(myString, "{[") />

<cfloop index="i" from="1" to="#arrayLen(myArray)#">
  <cfset myArray[i] = "{" & listFirst(myArray[i], "}]") & "}" />
</cfloop>

<cfdump var="#myArray#" />
<hr>

<cfset myList = arrayToList(myArray, "|") />
<cfdump var="#myList#" />
```

***TryCF.com Gist:***
https://trycf.com/gist/6035ddc5cd3daa81bc0943f1af33323a/lucee5?theme=monokai